# Facebook API Website - JavaScript SDK - Confused

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been looking around Facebook's guides about logging into my website with their API. For now I've looked into the JS SDK. I am a PHP programmer but thought the JS SDK would be easier... at least I thought so. I am really confused by, everything really. Here is some simple questions:

1. If I "just" wan't to use the API for logging into my site, and nothing else, would I then be using PHP or JS?
2. Now - if using JS - how do I interact with Facebook properly? Right now it's logging into facebook and login out of facebook. What I wan't is to just grant access to my app (like normal) and logout of app.
3. If still using JS - how do I make if sentences determining if a user is logged in? I mean, if a user is logged in I wan't to show some user informations, and the possibility to edit settings.

All in all I think I've maybe misunderstood the function of JS SDK or what? I am really confused, and I really need some help with getting onto the road again.

*** NEW ***

So, everytime that I wanna show something to a logged in user I have to use the FB.getLoginStatus();?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q- If I "just" wan't to use the API for logging into my site, and nothing else, would I then be using PHP or JS?**

A- You can use both. See- [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/)

**Q- how do I interact with Facebook properly?**

A- Once the user authorizes the app, you can use any methods through API call (using your facebook object). Go through this- [JS SDK Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript)

**Q- how do I make if sentences determining if a user is logged in?**

A- You can use [FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)

Comment: please watch my question, I will add some more.

Comment: Not exactly. If you get the response.authResponse from FB.login, that means the user is successfully logged-in, then you can use any function you want. You may not even requir to call FB.getLoginStatus. Its all upon you how you want to proceed.

Comment: I mean: If I wan't to show images uploaded to my page (not images from fb) from the user logged in, how would I do that? I am very confused. Don't I need some if sentence like in php like: if($_SESSION['loggedIn']){ //show images }

Comment: See, I'm again saying that after the user is successfully loggedin, call any method eg: FB.api("/me/accounts"); etc.
I'm not sure  whether you can fetch the pics uploaded by the user or not. You can test this here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
write me/accounts in the box, then select the page from result.

Comment: Uhm, I am talking about, when a user is logged in via facebook, he must have an account on my site, else I can't get settings for him, right? He need some kind of id to get contact informations etc. how would I do this?

Comment: see the code below by Vishwesh Shetty, you can see scope:email; now after successful login (i.e. user authorizes the app), your app can fetch the email (you can define more in permissions) and by calling ('/me'); you can obtain the facebook id of the user.

Comment: So I check if email exists in database, if it doesn't add the facebook user id to database and use that?

Comment: Oh wait.. Shouldn't I just be using the facebook user id when they have to upload an image to my site? Or do I have to make a user in my database?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21384/discussion-between-kolind-and-shadowfax)

Comment: IF you maintaining the database for each useR? In this case use ('/me') after login, this will return the unique ID for the user. Match this Id in your database. Your problem statement is quite unclear, go through the getting started for fb api once.

Answer (score 1):

I recently made this code to explain a friend about Facebook Login functionality. There are detailed comments for every line of code. I am not sure if this is the best way to do it. But this is very simple to understand.

```
<?php
//include Facebook library File
include_once "src/facebook.php";
//Application Configurations
//Declare variables app_id,app_secret, we get app_id,app_secret values from app dashboard. 
$app_id     = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

// Create our application instance
//we create $facebook instance and would use it to access various Facebook library functions
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'     => $app_id,
    'secret'    => $app_secret,
    ));

?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
//  $facebook->getUser() is a function which would return a user id if someone is
//  logged in  on Facebook currently (In some other window or tab)
// We may or may not have this data based 
// on whether the user is logged in.
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know 
// the user is logged into Facebook,
// but we don’t know if the user has authorized our application.
// i.e whether user has already given our app permissions to access his data or not
if ($user) {
 /*
 * Facebook user retrieved
 * $user : Holds the Facebook Users unique ID
 * */
 try {
        // We try to get users data assuming he has authoized are app if we dont get data we display login button in catch block.
        $userinfo = $facebook->api('/me');
        echo "<br/>User id : ".$userinfo['id'];
        echo "<br/>Name : ".$userinfo['name'];
        echo "<br/>Gender : ".$userinfo['gender'];
        echo "<br/>Email : ".$userinfo['email'];
        echo "<br/>Location : ".$userinfo['location']['name'];
        echo "<br/>Image : <img src='https://graph.facebook.com/".$userinfo['id']."/picture' >";
        echo "<br/><br/><br/>Similarly we can get lot more information about user like work experience, dob etc more details would be shared later /We use this data to prefill registration form for user. ";
        echo "<br/><br/>Below is dump of entire array which shows all available data it carries<br/><br/>";
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($userinfo); 
            echo '</pre>';
        //Similarly we can get lot more information about user like work experience, dob etc more details would be shared later
        //We use this data to prefill registration form for user.

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
         // Display Facebook login button - Requires Facebook JavaScript SDK (Below)
         echo '<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" scope="email,user_photos"></fb:login-button>'."\n";
         $user = NULL;
     }
} else {
 // No user logged in currently Display Facebook login button - Requires Facebook JavaScript SDK (Below)
 echo '<fb:login-button show-faces="false" width="200" scope="email,user_photos"></fb:login-button>'."\n";
}
?>
<!--Below code is required to use FAcebook Javascript SDK/Library, Before this we have been using Facbeook PHP-SDK/Library --> 
<div id="fb-root"></div> <!-- A div element with id "fb-root" is required. Facebook JS SDK will auto create this element if it doesn't exist , But we will anyways create it-->
<script>
// window.fbAsyncInit will execute code within it asynchronously i.e without affecting the load time.
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
//Below code Initializes Javacript SDK, appid is same as one defined in fbaccess.php
 FB.init({
 appId : '<?=$app_id?>',
 cookie : true,
 xfbml : true,
 oauth : true
 });

//Below code tells the script to refresh whenever user logins or logouts. 
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) { window.location.reload(); });
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (response) { window.location.reload(); });
};

// Copy paste code to load the Facebook JavaScript SDK into the page
(function(){var e=document.createElement('script');e.async=true;e.src=document.location.protocol+'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);}());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In Javascript you can Call a function like this :

```
function login(){
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {                                    
                alert(response.authResponse.userID);
                //Authenticated user.
        } else {
        // Unauthenticated user display authentication popup
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) { 
                    alert(response.authResponse.userID);
                    //User authenticated.
                } 
            else{                                           
                    alert("Please allow authentication to proceed!!");
                }
            }, {scope:'email'});
        }
    });
}
```